# Find the inverse of $I_n-uv^T$

Tags: matrices

There are two $n$-components column vectors $u$ and $v$. $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Find the inverse of $I_n – uv^T$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't got any idea of how to solve it. I've tried to use Gauss Elimination, but I failed.

Comment: See [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula). Highly likely that variants of this has been answered several times on this site.